# Kotlin: Can an abstract super class have an abstract constructor?

Tags: kotlin

I have just written this, which is fine as far as it goes:

```
import com.github.salomonbrys.kotson.get
import com.github.salomonbrys.kotson.int
import com.github.salomonbrys.kotson.jsonObject
import com.google.gson.JsonElement
import com.google.gson.JsonObject

abstract class BatchJobPayload {
    abstract fun toJson(): JsonObject
}

class BookingConfirmationMessagePayload(val bookingId: Int) : BatchJobPayload() {
    constructor(payload: JsonElement) : this(payload["bookingId"].int)

    override fun toJson() = jsonObject(
        "bookingId" to bookingId
    )
}
```

But I'd like to insist, if possible, that all classes that extend `BatchJobPayload` implement a secondary constructor with the signature
`constructor(payload: JsonElement): BatchJobPayload`, which is to be used for deserializing.

`BookingConfirmationMessagePayload` has such a constructor but only because I put it there, not because `BatchJobPayload` insisted upon it...

Comment: I don't think you can do this.. If you give `BatchJobPayload` a constructor,  all sub classes must call this super constructor, but I don't think it helps

Comment: There's no point in having both constructors compulsory. If you'd rather have someone pass `bookingId` always, why not just remove the default constructor completely? What purpose does it serve then? Insead put a default value for it, maybe?

Comment: @Sourabh the purpose is to always have _two_ ways of making a subclass of `BatchJobPayload`: directly using the primary constructor and indirectly when all you have is a JSON string which is the result of calling `toJson` on an existing instance.  See [serialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization).

Answer (score 1):

You can't enforce a super constructor, but you can have factories with a spawn method enforced that returns a subclass of `BatchJobPayload`, which allows you to make sure classes will be constructable.

It would look something like this:

```
class JsonObject // Included to make compiler happy

abstract class Factory<T> {
    abstract fun make(obj: JsonObject): T
}

abstract class Base {
    abstract fun toJson(): JsonObject
}


class A(val data:JsonObject):Base() {
    override fun toJson(): JsonObject {
        return JsonObject()
    }
}

class AFactory: Factory<A>() {
    override fun make(obj: JsonObject): A {
        return A(obj)
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val dummyJson = JsonObject()

    var factory = AFactory()
    var instance = factory.make(dummyJson)

    println(instance)
}
```

Comment: I was unable to get this code working.  I'm not sure you can construct an object in Koltin using a type parameter as show above: `return A(obj)`...

Comment: @gtod I added a main method to show how to use it, which runs successfully on my end, what kind of issue are you facing?

Comment: Sorry @jrtapsell, you are right and I got it to work thusly:

Comment: No problem, I should have included the main method from the start

Comment: In fact I changed the defn. of `A` to `class A(val id: Int) : Base() {` and in `AFactory` the override is now `override fun make(obj: JsonObject) = A(obj["id"].int)`. This works but because in general the `A`, `B` etc. classes will need their own unique constructors, what is the point of the type parameter (have you seen my own answer which doesn't use one)?

Answer (score 1):

A workable option I came up with as as follows:

```
interface BatchJobPayload {
    fun toJson(): JsonObject
}

interface BatchJobPayloadDeserialize {
    operator fun invoke(payload: JsonElement): BatchJobPayload
}

class BookingConfirmationMessagePayload(val bookingId: Int) : BatchJobPayload {
    override fun toJson() = jsonObject(
        "bookingId" to bookingId
    )
}

class BookingConfirmationMessagePayloadDeserialize : BatchJobPayloadDeserialize {
    override operator fun invoke(payload: JsonElement) =
        BookingConfirmationMessagePayload(payload["bookingId"].int)
}
```

Now you can deserialize a `BookingConfirmationMessagePayload` object from a `JsonElement` as follows:

```
BookingConfirmationMessagePayloadDeserialize()(payload)
```

(The `invoke` operator is just some syntactic sugar here which may border on the obtuse...)

Actually I still prefer the original code which is less verbose ---  a developer needing to subclass `BatchJobPayload` in the future may initially neglect to define a constructor that takes a `JsonElement` but they will surely realise their omission once they have just a string of JSON which they need to turn into an instance of their new class...