# Prevent dependency on a class in Java / Kotlin, but allow extending

Tags: java, android, oop, design-patterns, kotlin

I wish to create a useful base Java class with a few protected methods and hooks so subclasses can be easily implemented.

However, I wish this class to ONLY be available for deriving a subclass, but not available as a dependency.
The reason is to prevent some junior/careless developers from coupling their code to this base class.

For example, if my base class is called BaseActivity.java, anyone can create their own

```
public class MyNewActivity extends BaseActivity
```

But no one can refer directly to BaseActivity with a field or method signature, for example this should not be allowed:

```
public void doSomethingOnBaseActivity(BaseActivity activity);

private BaseActivity someField;

public BaseActivity getActivity();
```

Is there any way to accomplish such a restriction in Java?
Maybe in Kotlin this would be possible?

EDIT:
This is NOT a duplicate of [Kotlin: Can an abstract super class have an abstract constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087699).
I wish to prevent dependency on the base class, not just instantiation. "Abstract" doesn't help here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin: Can an abstract super class have an abstract constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087699/kotlin-can-an-abstract-super-class-have-an-abstract-constructor)

Comment: you can either use an `abstract` class or throw an `Exception` on direct instantiation.

Comment: @MartinZeitler
No this is not what I asked. I wish to prevent dependency, not just instantiation.
A reference to this base class should not be allowed - only deriving from it.

Comment: this is non-sense, because you might confuse `import` with `dependencies`; one probably cannot prevent the `import` (unless simply deleting the class or removing the dependency), but one can prevent it's instantiation.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I don't care about "import", I care about people coupling their code to the class. If someone derives from this base class, it's fine. If someone creates a method that receives or returns a reference to the base class, it's not good and I wish to prevent.

Comment: that's exactly what an `abstract class` does; the `abstract` keyword can also be applied to methods in that base class, which must be implemented by those which extend it. the only down-side of that is, that one cannot cast to that base-class anymore (if required, better just add a no arguments constructor which throws an exception).

Comment: @MartinZeitler
Please read my question carefully, you are not answering it. I know what "abstract" is and it doesn't accomplish my goal.

Comment: So there's no way to get an instance of `BaseActivity` because it's abstract. So even if you declare a field of type `BaseActivity` it's going to be set with a concrete object. So if you call a method on it, it would call the concrete implementation. I'm not sure I understand what more do you want. Have good documentation and accept the fact that you can't babysit every starting programmer.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I wish to prevent referencing from anywhere, except when deriving. "abstract" does not prevent referencing.
For example, the method signature "void something(BaseActivity activity)" should be disallowed.
But deriving: "public class DerivedActivity extends BaseActivity" would be allowed.

I know this is impossible to achieve by classic Java so I am looking for some good design pattern that might allow that. Or in Kotlin if it makes it possible.

Comment: If I wanted to answer this noob question, I would have left an answer. one cannot reference an abstract class in the signature - simply because it cannot be instanced and therefore it can not be cast - the method signature demands an instance. and Kotlin certainly cannot provide any more possibilities, since it compiles to Java byte-code - which runs against exactly the same framework.

Comment: another one possibility might be: abstract class -> implementation class -> extends implementation class. this provides the abstract class - where it's companion implementation class can be cast and/or used in a method signature. it really depends on what the situation, which pattern suits betters - the is no best recipe, but only 2-3 possible ways to choose from.

Comment: Of course you can reference an abstract class in Java, the same as you can reference an interface. That's the whole point of polymorphism. I have no idea what you're talking about, and you're not doing yourself a favor with the "noob" word.

Comment: If it is a problem that `BaseActivity` is a *thing* that you can *expect* as an "interface", then clearly the problem is that `BaseActivity` ***exists*** at all in the codebase. Consider using interfaces with default methods, instead of putting them all inside a class where behavior is shared via inheritance. IIRC default methods are desugared if you enable Java 8 features in your Android project via the right Gradle configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. This answer is true for all types, whether abstract or not, interface or class. When you are in the scope of a class (e.g. same package), and this class is not sealed then everybody in this scope can inherit it. As long you are inside the scope, you can reference this type. That's the point of access modifiers. It doesn't make sense to allow extension of a type but not referencing it. This contradicts the concept. Why would you want to do that? You can't remove that base class anyway because that would break the code of all inheritors. There is no point in allowing extension but disallowing referencing. What is the reason for this. Maybe there is a different way to accomplish your goal. The very moment somebody inherits from a type creates the dependency. This dependency is called inheritance. The subtype is a supertype. You can't hide this fact from the compiler.

If you want to omit a dependency but reuse code or provide a template of the code then don't use a type. You could use file templates or a code generator to generate the reusable code (like code snippets).

Comment: Your answer is legit and I understand that in the language's level, you can't do that. So I am looking for some design pattern \ some way to complement my goal.
I explain in detail in the comments to @EugenPechanec's answer.

Comment: @SirKnigget This is not language level. It is compiler level. References are compiler business

Comment: @SirKnigget You can't use a type without creating a dependency to it. That's what a dependency is.

Comment: @SirKnigget You could use file templates or code generator to generate the portion of the code you want to reuse

Comment: To make it clear - I don't care about the compiler level dependency.
All I care about is to prevent people from using the BaseActivity type as a reference and making components depend on it, for example holding it as a field, receiving it in a method call, etc.
Deriving is the only intended usage for BaseActivity and no one except the derived classes should know that BaseActivity exists.

Is that clearer?

Comment: @SirKnigget  "I don't care about the compiler level dependency" And I say this is not possible. How can it? Your code has to compile. There is no chance to avoid anybody to use this type inside its scope. Whether for subtyping or referencing. When subtyping you already are referencing it. If you want to provide ready to use code but not as a dependency you only can use code generating. E.g. most IDEs support code templates. You the would use a keyboard shortcut to insert this code snippet. This is what you are  looking for.

Comment: @SirKnigget Inheritance doesn't make sense if the base type is not allowed to reference. It's not sensible. a contradiction in itself. It's not supported by any language I know.

Comment: You are right about inheritance, but in this case, I only wish the base class to be a skeleton (reusable code) for creating derived classes. It seems that language-wise this is not possible, so I might go with the lint direction.

Answer (score 1):

First off, let's address the *why*. *Why* are you looking for this? **You're looking for a way to prevent the consumer from calling unwanted methods on a base class.**

If you think you're looking for something else, think again. If you just *want* to hide it, think again. The end user will not care about implementation details at all.

---

If you created the base class, then **don't publish an API that allows this** in the first place. There was a chapter on this specifically in [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882).

If your base class extends another base class you're in trouble. **You can't hide already published API**, if you're extending and not encapsulating.

> I wish this class to ONLY be available for deriving a subclass, but not available as a dependency. Is there any way to accomplish such a restriction in Java? Maybe in Kotlin this would be possible?

No. This is not an opinion, this is by design.

---

There may be a convoluted way to hide methods of parent classes but not on the class the consumer interacts with (extends).

You could have several layers of base classes each within its own Gradle module and setup `implementation` type dependency but then If you can extend the class, if you can see it, reference it, you can also use it anywhere.

Imagine this:

- consumer module -> `ConsumerActivity` extends `ExtensibleActivity`
- your library module -> `ExtensibleActivity` extends `BaseActivity`
- your base library module -> `BaseActivity` extends `Activity`
- Android SDK -> `Activity`

Consumer module only sees what's inside "your library module". It knows about `ExtensibleActivity` but it can't see any of its super types. The consumer can still reference `ExtensibleActivity` and its methods. The side effect is because the superclasses are not known from consumer's point of view, you *can't* pass an instance of `ExtensibleActivity` as an `Activity` because the type system doesn't know it extends an `Activity`, because it doesn't see the `BaseActivity` intermediary type. Here's a graph of what the consumer sees:

```
ConsumerActivity -> ExtensibleActivity -> BaseActivity (doesn't exist) -> ??? (don't know)
```

At this point you just have to ask yourself "should this have extended `Activity` in the first place?".

This is just terrible to work with. Lot of wasted effort for something that you shouldn't need to worry about.

---

If you want to conceal something, use **composition over inheritance**. Put your logic inside a `Fragment` or, better yet, **put your logic inside a custom lifecycle aware component**. That way you're in total **control over the API**. Make it so you don't have to worry about where it gets called from.

Write **good documentation** for your code and a **usage manual**.

And kindly allow me to break your damn library if I choose to use it incorrectly.

Do you have multiple methods in your API? Great! Nobody will prevent me from calling them out of order. You can write in your manual how it's supposed to be used, but ultimately, I'm writing my program, using your library, and if I do it wrong, then it's my fault when it breaks. This is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. To clarify - I don't care if the parent base classes are being exposed. People can reference "Activity", "AppCompatActivity", etc. all they want.
I wish to specifically disallow referencing "BaseActivity", so the ONLY possible usage for BaseActivity would be extending it.
I have my reason behind it, which is bad programmers in a previous project that I took care of, who have created a gigantic "base activity" that everything depended on from the outside.

I wish to create a BaseActivity, which is impossible to reference, only derive.
I hope it makes sense.

Comment: And I agree regarding good documentation, usage, etc. I was just wondering if I can enforce what I wish using Java/Kotlin features.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but that's not how it works. Minimise the public API, favor composition over inheritance, don't leak implementation details. Those are your weapons to write more maintainable, easily usable code. Having my own experience with "bad programmers" (and understanding that I started as one myself), experience and learning helps. But that's not your responsibility. Unless you're in charge of education at your workplace, of course ^^

Comment: It's not some library I'm writing, the BaseActivity would be completely accessible and modifiable by programmers in the project.
Regarding composition over inheritance I agree, but having a BaseActivity would reduce even more boiletplate than composition allows.

Comment: OH! Now I get it, you're trying to hide the BaseActivity which is out of your control. You¨re out of luck, the only thing is that you could override the methods you want to hide and annotate them with `@Deprecated`. It would be less important in IDE suggestions and it's a clear message that this shouldn't be used. That's pretty much it.

Comment: In Kotlin you could mark it as [`@Deprecated` with level ERROR](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-deprecated/index.html)  in which case the code wouldn't even compile. I think that's what you're looking for. If the consumer is using Kotlin too, it wouldn't compile. If they're using Java then it would probably compile, I'm not sure. I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Not exactly. I do have control over BaseActivity, but I wish to create a skeleton for the project in which programmers would not easily abuse it and add stupid public stuff to the BaseActivity when they're lazy. I can technically just supervise and enforce that BaseActivity will never have any public methods or fields, so that there is no value in referencing it. If there was a programmatic mechanism for enforcing that, it would be nice. Maybe some lint rules for the project.

Comment: So what about this: You have a list of methods that are defined in BaseActivity. This is generated once at the beginning. Then at build time you generate a current list of methods and compare them. If there is a mismatch, build will fail. This will cost time so it's not advisable to run in debug mode. You could use [japicmp plugin](https://github.com/melix/japicmp-gradle-plugin). Because it's so time consuming you should also have, exactly, a [custom lint rule](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules) that checks BaseActivity API and reports errors while editing.

Comment: Or ditch japicmp. because you're already doing the lint rule, you can have the (production) build fail on your lint error.

Comment: Something like that. I don't mind more protected / private methods in the BaseActivity, just prevent public fields/methods, so there is no value in referencing BaseActivity from anywhere and no one can create coupling to it.